# Get text from span above link - Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, text, element, closest

Hi I am trying to get the text from a span element directly above a link.

```
$(this).closest("span").text()
```

Full Code:

**JS**

```
$boxes.find('.portlet-header .portlet-maximize').click(function() {
// returns the rel of the link fine   
var widHtml = $(this).attr('rel'); 
// get text from span above link (not working)
var widTitle = $(this).closest("span").text()
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="portlet-header">
<span class="widTitle gmIcon">text I want to get</span>
<a rel="widgets/dashboard/max/goal-mouth" class="portlet-maximize"></a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

[closest()](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) walks the ancestor tree. Since your `<span>` element is a sibling of the anchor, not an ancestor, you should use [prev()](http://api.jquery.com/prev/) instead:

```
var widTitle = $(this).prev("span").text();
```

Comment: thanks, makes sense, but does not seem to work. This does however


`$(this).siblings('.widTitle').text()`

Comment: This should work with the markup in your question. Maybe your actual markup is different?